# Base and derived classes C++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

A few days ago, I wanted to dive into the C++ world. I'm studying the base and derived class concepts. Could someone explain the nuance going on with the following two code snippets?

```
class A
{
    private:
    virtual int GetValue() { return 10; }

    public:
    int Calculate() { return GetValue()*1.5; }
};

class B: public A
{
    private:
    virtual int GetValue() { return 20; }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    std::cout << b.Calculate() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

> The output is 30 but 15 was expected

```
class A
{
    private:
    int m_data;

    public:
    A(): m_data(GetValue()) {}
    int Calculate() { return m_data*1.5; }
    virtual int GetValue() { return 10; }
};

class B: public A
{
    public:
    virtual int GetValue() { return 20; }
};

int main()
{
    B b; A* ap;
    ap=&b; 
    std::cout << ap->Calculate() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

> The output is 15 but 30 was expected
>
> Can someone explain and help me understand the reasoning? Something is wrong with my thinking on this concept, but I am unable to figure it out.

Comment: Explain why you thought your code would give those values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First case:

This is trivial. You have an instantiated instance of `B`, and you compute `return GetValue() * 1.5;` which uses `B::GetValue()` as you've marked `GetValue()` to be `virtual` in the base class. Hence 20 * 1.5 is evaluated.

Second case:

Not so trivial. You are calling `GetValue()` in the base member initialiser to set a value for `m_data`. Standard C++ dictates that the base class `GetValue()` method will be called in that case. (Informally think of this as being due to class `B` not being constructed until class `A` is fully constructed). Hence 10 * 1.5 is evaluated. Interestingly, if `GetValue()` was *pure virtual*, then the behaviour of the program would have been *undefined*.

---

Reference: [Why a virtual call to a pure virtual function from a constructor is UB and a call to a non-pure virtual function is allowed by the Standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185990/why-a-virtual-call-to-a-pure-virtual-function-from-a-constructor-is-ub-and-a-cal)

Comment: Your reply is so helpful, clear, and complete. It was very important for me to understand this before going forward in the course. Thank you so much. I got it now.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code for the second example:

```
class A
{
private:
int m_data;

public:
A(): m_data(GetValue()) { std::cout << "Init m_data and A ";}
int Calculate() { return m_data*1.5; }
virtual int GetValue() { std::cout << "GetValue from A ";return 10; }
};

class B: public A
{
public:
B() { std::cout << "Init B "; }
virtual int GetValue() { std::cout << "GetValue from B"; return 20; }
};

int main()
{
B b; A* ap;
ap=&b; 
std::cout << ap->Calculate() << std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

It is the same as you already have but with outputs. You should get `GetValue from A Init m_data and A Init B 15`. I hope now you see why you have an output of `15`. With the outputs you should be able to reconstruct the execution order.